# Как подогнать разрешение к реальному телефону?

Tags: android, android-xml

Телефон: Samsung A23, разрешение 2408x1080.
Создаю в Android Sturio превью, настраиваю под реальный телефон, но картинка на превью и в реальности вообще разные(
код activity_main:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F5BCFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainTable"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#F5BCFF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="123456789"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textColor="#E76AFD"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button22"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainTable"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button28"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button32"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button29"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button20"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button29"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="%"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button32"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button30"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button28"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button25"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button21"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainTable"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button30"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="."
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button33"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button31"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button29"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button19"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button31"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="/"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button33"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button30"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button26"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button32"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="C"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button33"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button28"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button19"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="9"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button30"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button26"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button25"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button22"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button26"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="*"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button31"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button19"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button21"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button25"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="8"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button29"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button19"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button20"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button23"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button28"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button25"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button24"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button21"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button26"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button22"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button22"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="6"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button19"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button21"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button23"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button23"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button25"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button22"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button24"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button23"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainTable"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button24"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button20"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button23"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainTable"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button33"
        android:layout_width="232dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F1A2FF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
        android:text="="
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button32"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button29"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button29"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Манифест:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Calculator"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>`
```

[image: создание превью]
[image: превью2]
[image: превью]
[image: экран]

Comment: приложите разметку, так сложно сказать где проблема

Comment: Разрешение не самое главное!

Comment: @Andrew добавил разметку activity_main и манифест

Comment: А по моему не имеет значения на каком устройстве проверять, так как у всех аппараты разные и он должен отображаться одинаково на всех девайсах, а не только на A23.

Comment: текстом лучше, а не картинками

Comment: есть общие пожелания по оформлению вопросов на данном ресурсе, придуманные не мной, и лучше текст вставлять непосредственно в тело вопроса, сделать это можно нажав на кнопочку Править под вашим вопросом

Comment: @Andrew извините, исправил